# How can I create an instance of a Codable Struct?

Tags: swift, struct, codable

I am going round in circles trying to work with a Codable Struct. I can nearly get it to work, but I get an error at the end.

Here is a simple example:

```swift
struct Stuff: Codable {
    var title: String = ""
    var code: Int = 0
    struct Item {
        var name: String
        var value: Int
    }
    var items: [Item] = []
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws { }
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws { }
}

var items: [Stuff.Item] = []

items.append(Stuff.Item(name: "Apple", value: 1))
items.append(Stuff.Item(name: "banana", value: 2))

var stuff = Stuff(title: "test", code: 23, items: items)
```

On that last line I get the error

> Extra arguments at positions #1, #2, #3 in

Clearly the nested struct is OK. If I remove the `:Codable` and the `init()` and `func encode()` it works as I would have expected.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Reason:**

Since you've implemented `init(from:)` initialiser, so the default `init` is not available.

That the reason, it is not able to find `init(title:,code:,items:)`

**Solution:**

Implement the initialiser `init(title:,code:,items:)` manually. Also, conform `Item` to `Codable` as well.

Now, the `struct Stuff` must look like,

```
struct Stuff: Codable {
    var title: String = ""
    var code: Int = 0
    struct Item: Codable {
        var name: String
        var value: Int
    }
    
    var items: [Item] = []
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws { }
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws { }
    
    init(title: String, code: Int, items: [Item]) {
        self.title = title
        self.code = code
        self.items = items
    }
}
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that if one *does* need to implement `init(from:)`, it's better to do in as `extension Stuff: Codable {}`, which would keep the memberwise initializer for the type

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that I will need to customise the decoder and the encoder.

Comment: @Manngo If that is the case, then you need to implement `init(title:,code:,items:)` manually. Updated the answer.